# Force query parameter format in url

Tags: node.js, http, flutter, dart

I've got a method in my flutter app for querying in get request by passing parameters into url

```
 Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getData(
      {String path, String token, Map<String, String> params}) async {
    try {
      Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);
      Uri newUri = uri.replace(queryParameters: params); // http://some/path/?param=1...
      final http.Response response =
          await http.get(newUri, headers: APIHeader.authorization(token));
      final jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
      if (response.statusCode != 200) {
        throw ServerException(jsonResponse["error"]);
      }
      return jsonResponse['result'];
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }
```

where the url generated by `Uri` method is `http://some/path/?param=1...`

it works fine however if I want to use it for querying only by id then the query parameter format is only the id

`http://some/path/1`

and if I use the methode above and send params in format `{'id':'1'}` then I get url

`http://some/path/?id=1`

Is there any way to force that parameters to be in the format `../?id=1` in my back end or is there any way to make `Uri` method recognise these differences?

My backend router for the id is

```
router.get('/some/path/:id', controller.get);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do that work yourself.

The URI query parameters get put in the the *query* part of the URI.

That your service also accepts its parameters in non-query parts of the URI is not something the `Uri` class knows about. If you want something to be part of the *path* of the URI, you must put it there.

So, something like:

```dart
  Uri addParameters(Uri baseUri, Map<String, String> params) {
    if (query.length == 1 && params.containsKey("id")) {
      // ID only. Assume baseUri ends in `/`.
      return baseUri.resolve(params["id"]);
    }
    return baseUri.replace(queryParameters: params);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks... I didn't think I would be able to do that so I've created new method `getById` but I rather asked just in case this would be possible somehow.. Thank you for assurance